Google Big Query: SQL request length limitation
I have a question about GBQ and possibility to find big amount of rows at a time. My GBQ table contains 300M rows with 50 columns (f.e brand, model, color). Also, I have a 70K rows CSV file with only brand and model. And I need to enrich this CSV file using my GBQ table. The long query like: SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE ... or ... or ... does not help me, because GBQ can't work with such a long query (only 2500 CSV rows could be processed). Is it possible to rework the find-engine (enriching-engine) so it works correctly and find 50 columns for each of my 70k rows from CSV? Left Join also does not help, because it is processing for too long. Thank you!
P.S. Now I am using Python engine to enrich CSV file by separating the big request to the big amount of little requests.

Part 2:
I want to have a possibilty to enrich 70K CSV file with 300M GBQ table. I tried 2 cases:

Using long WHERE statement
Left Join to the little table of 70K rows

Long Where statement is impossible because of the limitations of query-length inside GBQ. That's why the Join case is better for me, as I understand. I want to combine different columns at a time to enrich my CSV file (f.e. Brand+Model+Color or at least Brand+Model etc) and this query tried to process for 20mins and no result were returned. I think LIKE operation works bad for me, but I need it because of this field includes 2-4 colors at a time. Maybe, we can upgrade this query:
SELECT *
FROM `phones_tbl` as table1
INNER JOIN `phone_list` as table2
ON
(
    table1.MANUFACTURER = table2.MANUFACTURER AND table1.MODEL = table2.MODEL
)
OR
(
    (table1.MANUFACTURER = table2.MANUFACTURER AND table1.MODEL = table2.MODEL)
    AND
    (table1.COLORS LIKE '%' || table2.COLOR || '%'
    OR table1.ADDITIONAL_COLORS LIKE '%' || table2.COLOR || '%')
)
OR
(
    (table1.MANUFACTURER = table2.MANUFACTURER AND table1.MODEL = table2.MODEL)
    AND
    (table1.CONNECTOR = table2.CONNECTOR OR table1.PHONE_JACK = table2.CONNECTOR)
)
OR
(
    (table1.CONNECTOR = table2.CONNECTOR OR table1.PHONE_JACK = table2.CONNECTOR)
    AND
    (table1.COLORS LIKE '%' || table2.COLOR || '%'
    OR table1.ADDITIONAL_COLORS LIKE '%' || table2.COLOR || '%')
)
OR
(
    (table1.CONNECTOR = table2.CONNECTOR OR table1.PHONE_JACK = table2.CONNECTOR)
    AND
    (table1.MANUFACTURER = table2.MANUFACTURER)
)
OR
(
    (table1.COLORS LIKE '%' || table2.COLOR || '%'
    OR table1.ADDITIONAL_COLORS LIKE '%' || table2.COLOR || '%')
    AND
    (table1.MANUFACTURER = table2.MANUFACTURER)
)
OR
(
    (table1.CONNECTOR = table2.CONNECTOR OR table1.PHONE_JACK = table2.CONNECTOR)
    AND
    (table1.MODEL = table2.MODEL)
)
OR
(
    (table1.COLORS LIKE '%' || table2.COLOR || '%'
    OR table1.ADDITIONAL_COLORS LIKE '%' || table2.COLOR || '%')
    AND
    (table1.MODEL = table2.MODEL)
)
OR
(
    table1.COLORS LIKE '%' || table2.COLOR || '%'
    OR table1.ADDITIONAL_COLORS LIKE '%' || table2.COLOR || '%'
)
OR
(
    table1.CONNECTOR = table2.CONNECTOR OR table1.PHONE_JACK = table2.CONNECTOR
);


Did you consider creating a temporary table in BigQuery with the 70K entries in the CSV?

it would help if you could provide a sample table with a few cols and the expected output from that sample, the query part the contributors can handle on Stackoverflow

@samuel-dion-girardeau thank you for your proposition. I have added the Part 2 to my question with experiment on your proposition.

@pratik-patil, thank you too.
Please, check my 'Part 2' which is connected to the first question. As I understand, the idea of Join is the only solution and I like it. But I need to get result which is processed very long for some reason.

Your join condition included in the edited question is incredibly complicated but I can see straight away that all those ORs mean you're going to get tonnes of matches for each row. Chances are you're blowing up the amount of result rows into the trillions and this is why the query hangs.

@paddy-alton, I understand. So, maybe, we have a possibility to separate these OR statements? F.e. use Join per each criteria separately, or something like this. SELECT with WHERE works good and very fast, but we need to divide 70k file into 35 files of 2k rows which is not the best solution, as I understand

That depends what you're trying to do. You haven't actually explained what the matching criteria are for, yet/what the desired behaviour is. Your first statement matches on model and manufacturer. Your second matches on model and manufacturer and colours; an expensive match that doesn't make much sense because it's the same as the first one but more specific, i.e. (1) OR (2) will always be True if (1) is True.

300M x 50 is not really a big deal by BigQuery's standards. This should absolutely be handleable in a single query.
First you want to upload your 70k row CSV as a table to BigQuery. Let's call this brand_model.
Next you want to do that LEFT JOIN to enrich the data.
    SELECT
        full_table.*,
      FROM
        your_dataset.brand_model
 LEFT JOIN
        your_dataset.full_table
        ON
           brand_model.brand = full_table.brand
       AND brand_model.model = full_table.model

This should return 70k rows with all the columns from full_table selected (assuming there is exactly one row - in both tables - for each combination of brand and model).
It shouldn't take very long to return, either (and can likely be sped up by clustering the full table on brand and model, if need be).

If this approach doesn't work for you, please give more details of what your performance requirements are and explain a bit more about the context in which you're making queries (for example, is this a manual query made via the UI or an automated query made via the API from a deployed system?).

thank you for your example. Please, check my 'Part 2' which is connected to the first question. As I understand, the idea of Join is the only solution and I like it. But I need to get result which is processed very long for some reason. Right now I am working inside GBQ interface, but then I will automate the process using Python.

Oh I see - in your edited question it's clear that you have a very complicated set of matching criteria you are trying to use. I think you are discovering that, to get good help on StackOverflow, it's really important to put lots of time into writing a clear question (rule of thumb: as much time as you've already spent trying to solve the problem) or multiple questions (making questions specific, not general, and asking just one thing per question).

I tried to make my question as short as possible. Previously, my colleague posted a big question here with a lot of examples. It looked very huge and we received no answers to it. That's why I tried to make it short and easy to read. Thank you for advice.
